# Entity Framwork SaveChanges() doesn't write to the database

Tags: entity-framework, savechanges

When I try to write an entity to the database with SaveChanges(), the call succeeds (returns 1), but does not actually write to the database.  Furthermore, by adding a savingchanges event handler, I am able to see that the item does in fact go through the save event with the correct properties (specifically, one object changed state and it is the new entity I sent).  When I read the database afterword, there are no new data rows.  There are no errors or thrown exceptions...

```
CommunityEF.Community c = new CommunityEF.Community();  
c.IdNumber = 0; //set key

c.Name = "Test";
CommunityEF.CommunitySystemContainer cc = new CommunityEF.CommunitySystemContainer(); 
cc.Communities.AddObject(c); // also tried "cc.AddToCommunities(c);"
int result=cc.SaveChanges(System.Data.Objects.SaveOptions.DetectChangesBeforeSave);
//result is always 1
```

I have review similar articles, but most of them have one line missing or incorrect (or even out of order).  In this case, I can see that it is passing through the system successfully from start to end, but it doesn't actually end up in the database.

Since it was asked in another article, here is my connection string:
`metadata=res://*/CommunityEF.CommunitySystem.csdl|res://*/CommunityEF.CommunitySystem.ssdl|res://*/CommunityEF.CommunitySystem.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\DB\Database1.sdf&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />`

Also, it shouldn't matter (but I know it does), but I am using VS2010 Express and it is a windows application, not a web application.

Thank you in advance for help on this matter.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but your SaveOptions enumeration may be the problem.  Try just calling

```
cc.SaveChanges();
```

without the enumeration.

Comment: The problem turns out to be that I forgot to set the DB properties not to copy.  I thought I had done this, but then had to restart from scratch (some problem in EF, I have a post about it on this site) and hadn't yet done it again for this project version.  Sorry for missing that obvious one, but it's been a long day.  My code works, but runs on the "local copy" under the bin/debug directory.